# Generated button on each table row with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, html-table, row

I have this code to generate buttons on each table row with PHP and HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <h2 class="text-center">Consulta</h2>
  <br>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td class="black"><span style="font-weight:bold">#</span></td>
      <td class="black"><span style="font-weight:bold">Data</span></td>
      <td class="black"><span style="font-weight:bold">Condomínio</span></td>
      <td class="black"><span style="font-weight:bold">Entrada</span></td>
      <td class="black"><span style="font-weight:bold">Título</span></td>
      <td class="black"><span style="font-weight:bold">Autor</span></td>
      <td class="black"><span style="font-weight:bold">Estado</span></td>
      <td class="black"><span style="font-weight:bold"></span></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $select = "SELECT * FROM database";
    $get = mysqli_query($cnn, $select) or die ('error');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>";
      echo $row['id'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['data'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['condominio'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['entrada'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['titulo'];
      echo "</td><td>";
      echo $row['autor'];
      echo "</td><td>";            
      echo $row['estado'];
      echo "</td><td>";    
      $html = '<form role="form" class="form-inline" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="thispage.php">';
      echo $html;
      echo '<button type="submit" name="alter'.$row['id'].'" id="alter'.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-default btn-xl">alter'.$row['id'].'</a></button>';
      echo '</form>';

      echo "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
</html>
```

And, of course, I want to use the buttons, but the code below won't work for me:

```
<?php
$var = "row['id']";
$var2 = "alter".$var;
if (isset($_POST['$var2'])) {
  echo('some code');
} 
?>
```

I saw some solutions with Javascript but I can only use PHP and HTML, so if anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: try this  $row["id"]

Comment: I know that part is working, because the button name comes out right if I make it show on each button.

Comment: change name of button to for example button1 then change this if $_POST['$var2'] to $_POST['button1']  .....and your code missing many logical thing

Comment: @mohade if I do that of course one of the buttons will work depending on the number, but I want all of them to work individualy.

Comment: ok will put answer and lets talk in answer comment

Comment: $var2 value is not used. The literal sting $var2 is used for the $_POST array. Use $var2 instead of '$var2' and php will return 'some code'. Also you generate a form per row. You only have to do that once surrounding the table. That makes the code much leaner.

Comment: @Sjoerd done that, still doesn't work unfortunely :(

Answer (score 1):

in simple way replace button to link

when you get the data put a link like that

```
echo " <a href='?id=".$row['id']."'>'alter'".$row['id']."</a>"
```

in next page use it like that

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
do something 
}
```

Comment: I did that and result is the same. Here's how the table looks (I have the button name showing on each button): https://imgur.com/ysLeEWl

pretend the names are "alter" and not "alterar"

Comment: ok im editing my answer ,if you want to use this id to do something with it

Comment: that worked! But I really need to use a button for it to look nice and pretty, how can I?

Comment: You can use CSS to modify <a> and make it like button or anything else

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST[$var2])) {
  echo('some code');
}
```

Try this. I guess `$var2` is treated as a string since it is covered with single quote

Comment: ah sorry I forgot to change that variable, but that's not the problem at all.

Comment: @Manuel  Updated the answer, Can you try this and let me know?

Comment: @Manuel How you are getting $row['id']. Can you print the value  and check that you are getting correctly?.

Comment: I already printed an the value is correct, each button name is "alterx" (x being the row number)

Comment: @Manuel I don't see any issues in the code except whatever mentioned above. The only thing you need to check is, cross verifying form button names against the printed value. Just inspect the button elements and see you are getting same button names while printing.

Answer (score 0):

If $var2 should read "alter1", "alter2", "alter3" etc. the line,

```
$var = "row['id']";
```

should read,

```
$var = $row['id'];
```

Craig

Comment: doesn't work because row['id'] is supposed to be a string to add to more code ( which is $var2)